# SELECT Statement returns ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following SQL schema:

```
Create table Employee (Id int, Salary int);
Truncate table Employee;

insert into Employee (Id, Salary) values ('1', '100');
insert into Employee (Id, Salary) values ('2', '200');
insert into Employee (Id, Salary) values ('3', '300');
```

And executing following query against database:

```sql
SELECT Salary as SecondHighestSalary
FROM Employee
ORDER BY Salary
    OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

It works on `Oracle XE 18`but on leetcode.com (which version of Oracle they run I don't know) it returns following error:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can use latest version of oracle db online at livesql.oracle.com - your query will 'work' there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error message indicates that you are using version lower than Oracle 12c(most likely Oracle 11g XE).

`OFFSET FETCH` was introduced in version 12c. You could easily check it by executing:

```
select * from V$VERSION;

SELECT Salary as SecondHighestSalary
FROM Employee
ORDER BY Salary
    OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
-- ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

**[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8b10186e2b83bb2fc3c22c5d3ef90095)**

Answer (score 3):

Three points.  First, in earlier versions of Oracle, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT Salary as SecondHighestSalary
FROM (SELECT e.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Salary DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Employee e
     ) e
WHERE seqnum = 2;
```

Second, this doesn't return the "second highest salary" -- under very reasonable interpretations of the phrase -- because the top salaries can be tied.  If you actually want the second highest *salary* (as opposed to the salary of the person second in the list of ordered salaries), then use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Third, you have these insert statements:

```
insert into Employee (Id, Salary) values ('1', '100');
```

Both `id` and `Salary` are declared as *numeric*.  Don't mix types!  The single quotes are not only unnecessary but misleading (although not harmful in this case):

```
insert into Employee (Id, Salary)
    values (1, 100);
```

Comment: excellent catch on the RANK() ! I hope they take your advice and get an A on their homework.